# After "ALTER TABLE MOVE PARTITION" new partitions are still created in the original tablespace

Tags: oracle

I moved all objects from one tablespace (hereinafter A) to another (B) .. but when a new partition is created it resises in the original one ..

How can I fix it? I have no idea what to do because everything is moved already

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER_PUBLIC.T_NO_CONNECT_CONTRACTS 
   (    
      CALL_DATE DATE, 
        CONTRACT_ID VARCHAR2(10), 
        FLAG_WF VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)
   ) 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE( BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE OWNER_PUBLIC 
  PARTITION BY RANGE (CALL_DATE) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')) 
    (PARTITION "P0"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2018-01-31 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 
  STORAGE( BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE OWNER_PUBLIC
```

Comment: ddl added ... re changing the dflt partition tablespace .. nope, where can I do that? I have changed the default tablespace for that particular user (all his new objects are created in the new one - which is correct)

Comment: Is `OWNER_PUBLIC` tablespace is the one where you want the new partitions to be created? Please go through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998627/how-do-you-move-a-partitioned-table-from-one-tablespace-to-another-in-oracle-11g

Comment: ok got it :) that helped ... missed that one -> DBA_PART_TABLES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving existing partitions to a new tablespace does not change the default tablespace at the table level.

To do that:

`alter table OWNER_PUBLIC.T_NO_CONNECT_CONTRACTS modify default attributes tablespace tablespaceB;`

[ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html)

[image]

[image]